# Invalid Syntax in Code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble with this bit of code.

```
print("The Overall Winner is,", sorted(data, key=lambda(x,y): sum(n[1] for n in y), reverse=True),sum(event[1] for event in event_data))
```

It is saying that invalid syntax and I don't know what is wrong with it.

This is the rest of the program

```
def main():
print("Welcome!\n")

n_events = get_number_of_events()
events_names = get_events_names(n_events)
print()
data = get_data(events_names)
print()
for house_name, event_data in data:
    print ("House " + house_name)

    for event_name, score in event_data:
        # note the use of tuple unpacking 
        print ("\tEvent: %s Score: %i" % (event_name, score))

print("The Overall Winner is,", sorted(data, key=lambda(x,y): sum(n[1] for n in y), reverse=True),sum(event[1] for event in event_data))
```

Thanks for any help possible.

EDIT:

Whole Program.

```
LOWER_BOUND = 0
UPPER_BOUND = 100

def get_score(house_name, event_name):
score = -1
while score < LOWER_BOUND or score > UPPER_BOUND:
    try:
        score = int(input("Please enter score for %s in the event %s:" % (house_name, event_name)))
        if score < LOWER_BOUND :
            print ("Score is too low, minimum score is %i.\nPlease try again." % min_score)
        if score > UPPER_BOUND:
            print ("Score is too high, maximum score is %i\nPlease try again." % max_score)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Input please enter an integer. Thanks")
return score

def get_number_of_events():
print("Please enter the number of events there is.")
while True:
    try:
        n_events = int(input(">>"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter only a number, Thanks.")
    if n_events > 100:
        print("WOW, that's a lot of events, please be reasonable. Thanks.")
    elif n_events < 1:
        print ("That's too few events! Try Again.")
    else:
        break
return n_events

def get_events_names(n_events):
print ("Please enter the events names")
events = []
for n in range(1, n_events + 1):
    event_name = input("Event %i name: " % n)
    events.append(event_name)
return events

def get_data(events):
data = []
while True:
    house_name = input("Please enter house names <<<Enter XXX when finished>>> :")
    if house_name.upper() == "XXX":
        break

def main():
print("Welcome!\n")

n_events = get_number_of_events()
events_names = get_events_names(n_events)
print()
data = get_data(events_names)
print()
for house_name, event_data in data:
    print ("House " + house_name)

    for event_name, score in event_data:
        print ("\tEvent: %s Score: %i" % (event_name, score))

print("The Overall Winner is,", sorted(data, key=lambda(x,y): sum(n[1] for n in y), reverse=True),sum(event[1] for event in event_data))

    print ("Please enter the events points in ascending order.")
    scores = []
    for event_name in events:
        score = get_score(house_name, event_name)
        scores.append([event_name, score])
    data.append([house_name, scores])
return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: Is that how your code is indented in your script, or did you make a mistake formatting it for the question? Also, please include the entire error text.

Comment: That's a great lesson here: one-liners might look cool, but they are much harder to debug! break this line into smaller steps and run them separately, I bet it won't be difficult to find the source of the error then.

Comment: Is this Python 3.x ?

Comment: @alfasin, good point; I was thinking that, but didn't get as far as mentioning it :P.

Comment: The error is lambda (x,y) the bracket to the left of the x says its invalid syntax

Comment: @AnandSKumar, just saying, in this case I don't think it would matter as far as a `SyntaxError`; the `print`'s would still "work" on Python 2.

Comment: I can post my whole program if you want?

Comment: @ReganKelly, you should include the entire error and traceback in your question. And the entire program, if you think it's relevant.

Comment: @AnandSKumar, of course, the tuple unpacking in the lambda could be an issue on Python 3 :).

Comment: @Cyphase , yep that is why I asked if its Python 3.x :D

Comment: @ReganKelly can you post an example structure of `data` as well ?

Comment: Here is a picture of an example https://gyazo.com/546efd92c742519305542d9353eb56ea

Comment: Read the error message, it's usually quite informative. In this case it points at where the syntax error is. Syntax error means that the statement cannot be parsed so you should be able to pinpoint it by breaking it down in parts (because as long as syntax error happens it won't matter if variables are undefined or similar because of missing context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the indentation in your actual program is correct, and that this is Python 3.x (since you seem to be using print as a function) , The issue would be in your lambda statement. A very small example to show your issue -

```
>>> a = lambda (x,y) : x+y
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = lambda (x,y) : x+y
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In Python 3.x , `tuples` cannot be part of the lambda's parameter syntax , that is you cannot directly unpack the element into multiple arguments (as could be done in Python 2.x). Instead you would need to use a single variable , and then access each element of the tuple using subscript. Example -

```
print("The Overall Winner is,", sorted(data, key=lambda x: sum(n[1] for n in x[1]), reverse=True),sum(event[1] for event in event_data))
```

Also, this seems unreadable to me, you should rather break it down into multiple lines (maybe save the intermediate results in different variables before printing , that would be more readable) .

---

As you say in the comments -

> For example in this picture I want the highest string with the total of the points to be printed  as shown in [picture.](http://gyazo.com/583f5ef505ae3e248c59c0a210903c36)

If you want the element with the highest value, then take the first element , and since elements of your array are lists again, use subscript to get its name. Example -

```
print("The Overall Winner is,", sorted(data, key=lambda x: sum(n[1] for n in x[1]), reverse=True)[0][0],sum(event[1] for event in event_data))
```

---

For latest requirement as per comments, do -

```
sortedlist = sorted(data, key=lambda x: sum(n[1] for n in x[1]), reverse=True)
print("The Overall Winner is,", sortedlist[0][0], sum(n[1] for n in sortedlist[0][1]))
```

Comment: I don't want it to print out this for example:

Comment: The Overall Winner is, [['test 5', [['Test 1', 77], ['Test 2', 99]]], ['Test 4', [['Test 1', 3], ['Test 2', 99]]]] 176 

176 Is the points for the highest house so I want to print the string of the highest house name

Comment: Is that your exact current output?

Comment: I did not change any of your logic, just moved from the assumption of Python 2.x to Python 3 .

Comment: For example in this picture I want the highest string with the total of the points to be printed

https://gyazo.com/583f5ef505ae3e248c59c0a210903c36

Comment: Sorry to bother you again would there be any way instead of doing this line:
print("The Overall Winner is,", sorted(data, key=lambda x: sum(n[1] for n in x[1]), reverse=True)[0][0],sum(event[1] for event in event_data))
To Display the overall winner points and house name?

Comment: Store the result of the `sorted()` in a variable and then access `[0][0]` for name, and the points using the sum(n[1] for n in <name of variable>[0][1])`

Comment: Can you help me out with this with what you have told me?
sort = sorted(data,[0][0],sum(n[1] for n in event_data[0][1]))
print("The Overall Winner is,", sort)
it comes up with TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: no, do the sorted in the normal way , don't do `[0][0]` inside it, I mean't acess the variable's index like that - `<element>[0][0]` . You should check out https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/ .

Comment: Can you write it out? I'm really confused. Sorry I'm quite new to python

Comment: Would there be any way to remove the key = lambda?

Comment: No , there wouldn't be, why?

Comment: I just want the program to look more simpler

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using argument unpacking in the lambda while using Python 3. Instead of doing this:

```
lambda(x,y): sum(n[1] for n in y)
```

Do this:

```
lambda item: sum(n[1] for n in item[1])
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Regan Kelly\Desktop\LOLOPLO.py", line 75, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Regan Kelly\Desktop\LOLOPLO.py", line 70, in main
    print("The Overall Winner is,", sorted(data, lambda item: sum(n[1] for n in item[1]), reverse=True),sum(event[1] for event in event_data))
TypeError: must use keyword argument for key function

Comment: @ReganKelly, you need to say `key=lambda item: sum(n[1] for n in item[1]`. Notice the `key=...'.

Comment: In that photo I just want it to print "House o" where the list is, so string for the highest points

Comment: @ReganKelly, you want to replace the list on the last line with "House o"?

Comment: So in the whole program shown this line:
sum(event[1] for event in event_data))
prints out the total points of the highest house, but I want to be able to print the House with that specific total points next to it

Comment: @ReganKelly, which would be "House o" in this case, right? And you want it to go where the list is now?